# GetLongPathName Undeclared

Tags: c++, dev-c++

When I try to compile my code with the function GetLongPathName(), the compiler tells me that the function is undeclared.

I have already read the MSDN documentation located @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364980%28VS.85%29.aspx. But, even though I included those header files, I am still getting the undeclared function error. Which header file(s) am I supposed to include when using the function?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>

#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLLEXPORT char* file_get_long(char* path_original)
{
    long length = 0;
    TCHAR* buffer = NULL;
    if(!path_original)
    {
        return "-10";
    }
    length = GetLongPathName(path_original, NULL, 0);
    if(length == 0)
    {
        return "-10";
    }
    buffer = new TCHAR[length];
    length = GetLongPathName(path_original, buffer, length);
    if(length == 0)
    {
        return "-10";
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

And, if it makes a difference, I am currently compiling using Dev-C++ on a Windows Vista 64-bit.

Comment: The exact error message would help us diagnose this. Also, what version of the Windows SDK are you using?

Comment: I compiled with VC9 on XP 32 bit. It gave error but not the one you mentioned. The errors were because of the inconsistent usage of `char*` and `TCHAR*` in code. Also, as a side note, `return "-10";` is a disaster in waiting. First of all it is const char* (or const TCHAR*) , so if somebody who calls your function tries to write something into it your program will crash. Also, if they do `delete[] buffer` (which is required for the normal case) again it will crash. If you can post the exact error then we may get some clue.

Comment: 114 dllmain.cpp `GetLongPathName' undeclared (first use this function)
  (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)


I am not sure as to what version of the Windows SDK I am using. How would I figure that out?

Answer (score 1):

Dev-C++'s support of the Windows API is not complete. Actually, it's not even close. It is entirely likely that the GetLongPathName function is not declared in winbase.h that is shipped with that compiler (Actually an old version of MinGW).

You can use the free compiler which ships with the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) to work around the problem. It is the same compiler that ships with Visual Studio, though it is commandline only.

You can also use [Visual C++ Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/Download-2008.aspx), which is free and provides features similar to DevCPP.